# Swift 3 func(completed issue

Tags: ios, swift3

I have the following code to create a function that parses some json data.

```
func getTrackData(completed: @escaping DownLoadComplete) {
    let getDataURL = URL(string: "https://tfmx-3ba7c.firebaseio.com/")!
    Alamofire.request(getDataURL).responseJSON { response in
        let result = response.result

        if let dict = result.value as? Dictionary<String, Any> {
            if let tr = dict["tracks"] as? Dictionary<String, Any> {
                if let name = tr["name"] as? String {
                if let trackId = tr["trackId"] as? Int {
                if let postcode = tr["postcode"] as? String {
                if let trackType = tr["trackType"] as? String {
                if let locId = tr["locId"] as? String {
                if let lon = tr["lon"] as? Double {
                if let lat = tr["lat"] as? Double {
                if let phoneNumber = tr["phoneNumber"] as? String {
                if let email = tr["email"] as? String {

                    for obj in tr {
                    let names = Tracks(name: name, trackId: trackId, postcode: postcode, trackType: trackType, locId: locId, lon: lon, lat: lat, phoneNumber: phoneNumber, email: email)
                    self.track.append(names)
                    }
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
                }
                }
                }
                }
                }
                }
                }
                }
            }
        }
        completed()
    }
}
```

when I call my function with

```
getTrackData()
```

I get the following error

missing argument for parameter 'completed' in call

it suggests I add

```
self.getTrackData(completed: <DownLoadComplete>)
```

but I'm not sure what to put in the bit that says

I have a similar function on another viewcontroller that doesn't require me to put anything in the brackets, but has the same parameters set up.

very confused.

Comment: If your question has been answered, please mark this answer as accepted.

Comment: You can also combine multiple `let` bindings in a single `if` statement.

Comment: that code is horrible . and your question title is also broken ;) please fix both to get more traction to this question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want an optional completion closure, declare it as optional:

```
func getTrackData(completed: DownLoadComplete?) {
}
```

And call the closure inside the function as optional

```
completed?()
```

Then you can call `getTrackData` without parameter.

Answer (score -1):

I've actually scrapped this code now, and implemented Firebase and using Firebase code, which is much tidier, and quicker.

Thank you for all responses